# Python return not returning variables

Tags: python, return-value

In this clock i made it initially asks for the user to input the time but when it wont return the time in variables. I get a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/Brett/My Documents/Programming/Python/clock.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(hour,":",mins,":",sec)
NameError: name 'hour' is not defined
```

I know the set time part dosnt need to be a function but i want to use it later.

```
import time

def setTime():
    print("Set time \n--------")
    time=input("24 hour or 12 hour \nType 1 or 2: ")
    if time=="2": hour12=input("AM or PM \nType 1 or 2: ")
    else: hour12=0
    hour=input("Hour: ")
    mins=input("Minute: ")
    print("--------")
    sec=0
    return time,hour12,hour,mins,sec

def printTime24():
    print(hour,":",mins,":",sec)

#def printTime12():

setTime()
print(hour,":",mins,":",sec)
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    sec+=1
    if sec == 60:
        sec=0
        mins+=1
    if mins == 60:
        mins=0
        hour+=1
    if time=="1": printTime24()
#    elif time=="2": printTime12()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return` statement returns *values*, not variables. And if nothing is done with the returned values, they are discarded.

You call `setTime()` but do nothing with the values it returns.

You need to store the returned values in new names:

```
time, hour12, hour, mins, sec = setTime()
```

I used the same names as used in the `setTime()` function itself, but I could just as well have given them different names:

```
foo, bar, baz, spam, eggs = setTime()
```

and then used those names in the rest of the code:

```
print(baz, ":", spam, ":", eggs)
```